# im using ajax for some dynamic aspect of my detail page of my site but im have very unsual results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using ajax for some dynamic aspect of my site's detail page, but I have unsual results. It appears when I perform my open call which looks like.

```
<script>
function showRSS(str) {
  if (str.length==0) { 
    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET",'?page=condition&q=' + str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body>

<form>
<input name="format" type="radio" onclick="showRSS(this.value)" value="hardcover" />
<input name="format"type="radio" onclick="showRSS(this.value)" value="paperback" />
</form>
<br>
<div id="rssOutput">RSS-feed will be listed here...</div>
```

My entire website gets duplicated again.

The condition page is:

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="hardcover") {
    echo 'hardcover';
}else{
    echo'paperback';
}
  ?>
```

Comment: You're sending the AJAX request to the URL of the original page, not the condition page.

Comment: the orginal page is ajax.php not condition.php so i dont see how im sending it to the original page im almost sure theres a issue with my url but i cant change it without changing everything in my website

Comment: In your `xmlhttp.open()` call you don't specify the URL. So it defaults to the URL of the page performing the AJAX call.

Comment: the test site is axesupermart.com. click the ajax link and choos an option and you will see exactly whats going on

Comment: specifying the url dosent work either i put http://axesupermart.com/?page=condition&q= into the url parameter and got the same thing

Comment: Are you using server rewrites to translate `?page=XXX` to a page on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the URL of `condition.php` in the `xmlhttp.open()` call:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", 'condition.php?q='+str, true);
```

Since you didn't have the page URL, it defaulted to the current page's URL. Your index page uses the `page=XXX` parameter to embed the contents of that sub-page into it. But you don't want to go to the index page with AJAX, you just want the sub-page by itself.

Comment: exaclty what i thought. is there some special way to specify the url with ajax?

Comment: It's just an ordinary URL. Just use the actual location of the script you want to call.